# Change the backend-view of mask - TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-mask

I try - in TYPO3 8.7.13 with the extension mask 3.1.0 - to build for example a CE with repeating records with fields for names - no problem.

But in the backend I can see only the first field. Is there any way to show both?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rmsg5qfd51blhrf/mask1.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

So there are preview templates they belong to the page view and not edit.
In edit mode you only see the label (this is given in the definition of IRRE in the TYPO3 core).
So you only can change the shown 'label' of the record. That means: using [`label_alt` in the TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8.7/Ctrl/Index.html#label-alt) (I recommend to use `label_alt_force` too):

```
'ctrl' => [
    'label' => 'surname',
    'label_alt' => 'givenname,surname',
    'label_alt_force' => 1,
],
```